# React NPM warnings related to file names in node_modules folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, node-modules

I am getting this error, and I am not sure why. I have read that it could because I'm mixing cases on my

```
import React from 'react';
```

statements, but they're all the same.

I've also read some other StackOverflow questions, but in the other questions it was always a name of their component at the top, not (webpack)

I also went through and checked all the casing on my other files, is it something to do with Babel or Webpack?

I have tried a couple things, but nothing is solving the issues.

```
(webpack)/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
* C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!c:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!c:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\symbol-observable\es\index.js

(webpack)/buildin/module.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
* C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!c:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!c:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\node_modules\ansi-styles\index.js
```

Comment: that means you imported same component with uppercase one location and lowercase in another location

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of the folder.

I was getting to the folder via

```
Start ==> Run ==> 
"cmd /c "start /max cmd /K "cd c:\Users\rickb\Documents\GitHub\Current-Portfolio\"" "
```

However, if I navigate there via

```
Start ==> Run ==> CMD
```

and then I just type the commands manually:

```
cd\
cd Users
cd rickb
etc...
```

the errors go away